# Prevent (via command line) a node from advertising topics

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am wondering if it is possible to prevent an existing node from advertising/publishing on a number of unnecessary topics.

In particular, p2os publishes on the following topics:

```
/sonar
/pose
/gripper_state
/motor_state
/aio
/ptz_state
/tf
/battery_state
/dio
```

I only care about /pose and /sonar, is there any way to tell the node not to broadcast  the other topics without rebuilding the node?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50486/prevent-(via-command-line)-a-node-from-advertising-topics/) by [autonomy](https://answers.ros.org/users/3784/autonomy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 435 on 2012-12-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, not unless the node exposes parameters or something similar that allow to switch this.

The only thing you can do is redirect those topics to somewhere else, if they interfere with other publications on the same topic.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know of a way to prevent a node from advertising, but it says [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers#publish.28.29_behavior_and_queueing) in the wiki that a publish() in roscpp doesn't actually do anything if nothing is subscribed.

---

Originally posted by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) with karma: 3562 on 2012-12-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-12-14**:
There might still be an overhead to actually compute the message to be published. In that case it's the node's responsibility to prevent that (e.g. the openni_kinect driver doesn't compute pointclouds unless the topic is subscribed)